# Diode resistance

Tags: diodes, resistance

Given these characteristics for a 1N4148 diode, what is the diode resistance?

[image]

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so... what's the formula for resistance?

Comment: The apparent resistance of a diode depends on the current through it, the polarity of the applied voltage, its temperature, and probably some other things.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Stack Exchange!

I assume you are referring to the series resistance that can be included in small signal models for diodes.

The values in the table include the junction potential of the diode. The small signal resistance alone can be read off of the slopes on the I-V plots provided in Figures 3,4 and 5 of the datasheet:

$$r=\frac{dV}{dI} \approx\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta I}$$ [Reference](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/ece315/Lectures/handout7.pdf)

I get the following for the [1N4148](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/1n914-d.pdf):

| Current Range | R |
| --- | --- |
| 2 - 3 uA | 18.75 kilohm |
| 20 - 30 uA | 1.875 kilohm |
| 0.1 - 0.2 mA | 375 ohm |
| 2 - 3 mA | 25 ohm |
| 10 - 20 mA | 5 ohm |
| 400 - 500 mA | 1 ohm |
| 600 - 700 mA | 0.5 ohm |

I note that multiple units and symbols are incorrect on the figures in the most recent datasheet.

Indicated currents in ranges represent exact points read from charts.

I reiterate that these are small signal resistances at a given bias current or voltage on the diode. A resistance implies a linear model while the diode I-V characteristic is highly non-linear. I note that the plots are semi-logarithmic.

I agree with @Hearth's comment that a fit will give the true resistance in a proper diode model that would be applicable for large and small signal operation. If you need precision, you should do this and use the model in simulation.

The method I give is more useful for approximate but quick use. For example, in switching applications, a maximum on resistance can be used as a worst case for design.

Comment: Calculating diode series resistance is best done by a best-fit regression using the ideal diode equation augmented by a series resistance--it's not the easiest mathematical calculations, but it gets you a number that has actual physical meaning and is constant across different bias currents.

Comment: @Hearth I agree. My method is approximate at best.

Comment: Are 4 (or even 3) significant figures justified for these resistances?

Comment: @SimonFitch Probably not since the input values are read off of graphs and approximate to begin with. But, I didn't bother with any truncation or rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Resistance is a characteristic of resistors and other resistive components (wires, for example). It is a constant value.

A diode is not a resistor. Hence, it is not characterized by a resistance. Even when people calculate the ratio of voltage and current for a diode at a given moment, the result is not a constant value: it depends on current and temperature. Therefore, that ratio is not resistance, because resistance is a *constant* characteristic, not any old ratio.

Engineer abhor this answer (as demonstrated by the downvotes) because it goes against their age-old misinterpretation of Ohm's law. But it is the scientific truth.

Therefore, your question is not answerable.